Write data periodically every 5 minutes in Flink on Beam
I have a Flink on Beam application, where I need to listen to a stream of incoming data, and write the data collected every 5 minutes using a custom Writer (implemented as a DoFn). Can you please help me how I can trigger my writer only when the window ends so that I can publish files every 5 minutes?

consider using Flink windows,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows can create a window with a size of 5 minutes.
